# passwordless user on gcp debian server

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, ssh, password-less

I'm hosting my file server on GCP debian 10 virtual machine and I want to create passwordless user so people could publicly download files from his home directory.

So I created new user, removed his password with passwd -d username, changed /etc/ssh/sshd_config file so it would allow this exact user to login with empty password and set chroot jail, restarted ssh service.

Unfortunately, when I'm connection via ssh into this user it still prompts me with a password.

This setup was working on the old server, configs are definitly correct and user definitely does not have password. I guess google implemented some additionl protection that dosen't allow me to do what I want.

Maybe someone had already bumbed into the same problem before?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux tools/apps. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: @kaylum, my bad, I was thinking where to put this question and because I saw another topic about gcp also on stack I decided to post my here as well. Is there any way to re-post it on another subforum?

Comment: I do not recommend using password-less SSH for file delivery. Every script kiddie on the planet will be attacking you - this will cost you egress bandwidth charges. Your example is a perfect case for a simple file based web server.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that it is not the best way to create a public file server, but the amount of users would be low (less than 10 in total), so I think chroot jail and correct user permissions would do the job. Anyway, I would like to know what exact vulnerabilities this solution could come with :)

Answer (score 0):

I reached the support and they said google doesn't support passwordless ssh connections.